# Ubuntu 22.04 failure to install with second HD at /home

Tags: 22.04

I installed 22.04 on a SSD, which works fine. However, the /home is on a separate HD and includes my data files. So I want to maintain these. When I use a custom install mounting this HD at /home, the system goes into the Ctrl-D mode and fails to startup GNOME. fstab contains the HD and its mounting location, yet, does not mount. i.e. cd-ing to /home shows an empty dir. Strange enough, when I close editing fstab in nano, it sometimes starts correctly, with the HD mounted at /home.

Anyone any idea what is going on and how to fix this? It used to work...

Comment: Is this separate HD an external USB drive? Then do not expect that to work reliably.

Comment: it is a separate HD, not USB. Used to work on 21.10 and before.

Comment: I assume that that separate HD is also formatted in ext4 or another file system that supports linux permissions.

Comment: Post fstab & UUIDs in question above. `cat /etc/fstab` & `lsblk -f`